# Session Oriented Asynchronous Architecture using Actors/AKKA

Tags: java, scala, session, akka, actor

The application we are building has a very simple concept: it receives incoming events from a Database and for each event it opens an **interactive session** with clients (in the event) by showing a menu. Based on client response, we move to the next state or take some concrete action (e.g. transferring funds).

Sessions are independent of one another. For example, suppose we get two events from the database saying clients A and B have reached a zero account balance state. In response to this event, we establish two connections to A and B show a menu which looks like the following:

```
 Please select an option:
 1. Get $5
 2. Get $10
 3. Ignore
```

For options 1 and 2, we ask for confirmation in the form of *second menu*.

```
 Are you sure?
 1. yes
 2. no
```

In this case, we'll have two sessions. Client A might choose option 1  (`1. Get $5`), whereas Client B chooses option 3 [in the first menu]. In the case of Client A, we'll present the *second menu* (above) and if the response is `1. yes`, we'll take some concrete action such as transferring funds and closing the session.

All client communication is done by a 3rd party system which takes JSON including client address, menu text and returns a response back to us. It takes care of actually maintaing the session on the wire, whereas we only need to do response correlation and dealing with session states.

We're expected to handle **50,000 of such sessions** in parallel.

Earlier, we designed the system in Java using SEDA model. Having heard of Actors, we are willing to check them out and write a quick PoC project (Java/AKKA). My questions are:

1. Has anyone had experience in building such kind of an application? Is 50,000 simultaneous sessions too much for AKKA to handle? (Note, we are only waiting for the response. When the response comes, based on the answer, we jump to the next stage, so it should be possible).
2. Which architectural stye/paradigm which best suit this problem in AKKA? Are there any frameworks out there for this kind of problem?

Comment: First, Akka is not an acronym.  Second, scaling Akka is straightforward if you avoid global state.  It makes horizontal scaling quite simple and most likely will not be your bottleneck (that's almost certainly going to be the database).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a reasonably easy use case with Akka's clustering.  50K sessions represented as an Actor instance for each is not very high load.  The reason to use clustering is only for fault tolerance.

The idea behind the architecture would be to have a web tier for handling RESTful requests that correspond to the sessions.  These requests would be sent to the Akka cluster and routed to the appropriate session Actor by session ID, or a new one would be created.  When a session is done, you stop the actor that is associated with it.

Note that the session actors should send themselves timeout messages via the scheduler.  Upon completion of handling a new message, the actor should schedule itself a message via the ActorSystem scheduler for 15 minutes (or whatever your timeout is).  When a new session message is received, that scheduled task should be cancelled, the new update handled, and then a new timeout scheduled.  There is a plausible race condition here, in that a timeout message may be in your session actor's mailbox queue AFTER a session message, but if your timeout message includes a time of when it was scheduled (the 15 minutes ago), you can check that and ignore it and reschedule another (just as a safety mechanism to avoid a memory leak).  If the time is greater than 15 minutes ago, then you stop the actor.

To see how the distribution of work to the session actors would be implemented, please see the "Distributed Workers with Akka and Java" template in Typesafe's Activator.  You will have a fully running clustered Akka application that you can tailor to do the session management as I've described above.  You can then export the project and work on it in Eclipse/IntelliJ/Sublime/TextMate/etc.  To download Activator, see [here](http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted).